# Mes dames, mesdames et leur prononciation

Tags: prononciation

Mon fils m'a dit entendre prononcer le mot « mesdames » (ou  en deux mots « mes dames », il n'en est pas sûr)  comme **mesdam**, c'est à dire en prononçant le s (il a entendu cette prononciation inhabituelle au collège). Je me demande s'il  a bien entendu et si oui, d'où vient cette prononciation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La locution « mes dames » ne peut être que rarement utilisée, comme elle signifie littéralement « les dames qui ont trait à un contexte particulier associé à quelqu'un », comme par exemple les dames qu'un peintre donné représente souvent dans ses peintures ; un tel personnage pourra dire par exemple « Mes dames sont souvent mal habillées, mais il est vrai que je ne choisi pas de représenter les plus riches. » La locution se prononce normalement, c'est à dire que le s de « mes » n'est pas prononcé. En ce qui concerne « Mesdames » le s n'est jamais prononcé non plus. On pourra peut être entendre cette prononciation anormale dans la bouche de quelqu'un qui n'a pas encore appris ce mot correctement, c'est à dire un étranger.